# Apache POI cell style does not work in Linux environment

Tags: java, excel, linux, formatting, apache-poi

The negative currency format is set using Apache POI:

```
CellStyle negativeCurrencyCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
negativeCurrencyCellStyle.setDataFormat((short)8);
```

which is `"$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"`
I am passing to the cell value a negative double value and applying the above cell style

```
cell.setCellValue(value);
cell.setCellStyle(negativeCurrencyCellStyle);
```

In windows environment the style works perfectly and I am getting red ($double_value) and the format in Excel is set to Currency.
However in Linux environment the  negative numbers are stored as text and the red font color is not applied. Any ideas how to make this work? I do not want to use a custom style and I need this number to be formatted as Currency. Thank you!

EDIT: The excel file is generated in Linux and opened in Windows. I am using Java 11 and POI 3.17.

It seems that POI format 7 works correctly with negative numbers. It does not use the red color but formatting is correct

Comment: What means "in Linux environment"? Does that mean you are opening the generated `Excel`file using another application than Excel? If so, then seems that application cannot work properly using Excel's built in formats. Then you needs using `DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat(); ... negativeCurrencyCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"));` to make a special defined format.

Comment: Cannot reproducing. For me `CellStyle.setDataFormat((short)8);` works as expected even if `apache poi` creates the workbook in `Ubuntu Linux` environment. If opened in `Excel` in `Windows` using locale settings `en_US`,  the cell shows ($1,234.56) in red when value is -1234.56.

Comment: Which version of POI are you using? Maybe that is my problem.

Comment: I am always using the current `apache poi` version. This is `apache poi 4.1.2` now. But it works for me using `apache poi 3.17` also.